# Tem como criar array no SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

No SQL Server Management Studio 2012 tem a possibilidade de criar array em uma procedure? Fiz uma pesquisa no google e não encontrei, ao que parece é usada uma tal de table variable para armazenar mais de um valor de um select.

Comment: Podes usar o concat e receber uma string separada por virgulas. Aí com um `split`  na linguagem em questão ficas com uma array.

Comment: Olá HeyJoe, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Comment: Olá, Ismael. Fiquei um bom tempo sem estudar programação. Estou voltando agora. Desculpa eu perguntar por aqui, mas tem como mandar mensagens privadas ao usuário?

Comment: Porque vc não guarda só uma string do seu json no campo tipo varchar mesmo ou text, usando o método do javascript: `JSON.stringify(dados);` e depois reconverte para objeto: `JSON.parse(dados);`

Answer (score 5):

Você pode tentar com o exemplo abaixo

```
select STUFF((select ', ' + descricao from PRODUTOS
              FOR xml PATH (''))
            , 1, 1, '')
```

[STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188043%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

[FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178107%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A unica forma que conheço é como você falou, criar (Tipo de TABELA definida pelo Usuário) da seguinte forma.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tp_IDsTable] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NULL
    -- mais campos
)
GO

create PROCEDURE TestePassandoArray
  @Id int 
 as

DECLARE @IDsTable tp_IDsTable -- aqui você criar um tipo como se fosse um array.  

insert into @IDsTable 
SELECT IdUsuario FROM tb_Usuarios where IdUsuario = @Id;

select * from @IDsTable

GO

EXEC TestePassandoArray 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Tentem isso:
https://github.com/klebermoura/mssql_array

são procedures que manipulam "array" atraves de "comandos" como "sp_create_array", "sp_set_array", "sp_get_array", "sp_list_array" e diversos outros, solução criada por mim para uma migração de um sistema em power builder para T-SQL.

--  PARA CRIAR UM ARRAY

```
exec dbo.sp_create_array 'll_dia'
```

--  SETAR UM(NS) VALOR(ES) NO ARRAY

```
exec dbo.sp_set_array 'll_dia', 1, 8
exec dbo.sp_set_array 'll_dia', 2, 59898
exec dbo.sp_set_array 'll_dia', 20, 'KLEBER MOURA'
```

--  OBTER UM VALOR DO ARRAY

```
declare @resultado varchar(8000) 
exec dbo.sp_get_array 'll_dia', 20, @resultado output
select @resultado
```

--  PARA EXIBIR O INDICE DE ARRAY PESQUISANDO PELO VALOR

```
declare @resultado int 
exec dbo.sp_search_array 'll_dia', 'kleber moura', @resultado output
select @resultado
```

--  LISTAR TODOS OS ARRAY´S CRIADOS POR MIM

```
exec dbo.sp_list_array
```

--  LISTA TODOS OS INDECES E VALORES DE UM DETERMINADO ARRAY

```
exec dbo.sp_list_array 'll_dia'
```

--  DISPOSE - APAGA TODOS OS INDICES DO ARRAY

```
exec dbo.sp_dispose_array 'll_dia'
```

--  PARA APAGAR UM ARRAY

```
exec dbo.sp_drop_array 'll_dia'
```

--  PARA EXIBIR O MAIOR INDICE (COM VALOR) DE ARRAY

```
exec dbo.sp_upperBound_array 'll_dia'
```

--  PARA EXIBIR O MENOR INDICE (COM VALOR) DE ARRAY

```
exec dbo.sp_lowerBound_array 'll_dia'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao criar o select de retorno da sua procedure, use a "String_agg()" para lhe auxiliar na construção do array.

Pode conferir como utilizar em: [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score -1):

O melhor que encontrei para a necessidade de hoje:

```
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT, name varchar(20))
insert into @myTableVariable values(1,'Roberto'),(2,'Gail'),(3,'Dylan')
select * from @myTableVariable
```

fontes:

- https://www.sqlshack.com/implement-array-like-functionality-sql-server/
- https://www.sqlshack.com/the-string-split-function-in-sql-server/